# How to get the length of a variable size array of structs?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, arduino-c++

I'm breaking my head trying to sort out this problem, and I have not been able to sort it out.
Given I have a struct:

```
struct person
{
     String name,
     String city,
     int age
}
```

I am reading a list of people from a certain file provided externally, and populating an array of this struct. This is done via a function, lets say

```
person * readFromFile(filename);
```

This function has the logic to read the file, create a variable size array of structs (adapted to the number of persons in the file), and return said array.

However, when I try to assign that outcome to a pointer, I'm not getting the elements of the array:

```
...
person * myPeople;
myPeople = readFromFile("/people.txt");
int n= ;// different things I-ve tried here
Serial.println("n is" + n);
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{ 
     Serial.println(myPeople.name + " (" + String(myPeople.age) + "), "+myPeople.city
}
```

I've tried several things to get the number of elements once the array is populated after researching how to do it, to know:

```
int n = sizeof(myPeople)/sizeof(myPeople[0]);
int n = sizeof myPeople / sizeof *myPeople;
int n = sizeof(myPeople) / sizeof(person);
int n = (&myPeople)[1] - myPeople;
```

But to no avail: I have 5 elements in the file, but n does never show the expected value (and of course the for loop breaks).

Can I get some assistance? what am I be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You need to store the length of the array explicitly, there is no way to retrieve it from a pointer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the 'sizeof' (a pointer pointing to an array)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeof-a-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)

Comment: Wrap it into a struct with more info: `struct personArray { struct person *data; int totalelements; int nelements; };`... every time you `realloc()` data (when `nelements == totalelements` and you need more space) adjust `totalelements`, everytime you add a person adjust `nelements`.

Comment: Or... `person * readFromFile(filename, &nReadPersons)` , where the latter is an out-argument, populated by your function and specifies the number of items in the returned sequence. All that's left it to actually write it now. Personally I prefer doing what @pmg suggests. it keeps codependent data together, nice and tidy.

Comment: uhm, thats an elegant alternative, let me try that! thank you!

Comment: Where do you actually allocate memory? And why on earth are you doing file handling on an Arduino?

Comment: Also, is this about C language or Arduino C++ language?

Comment: Another option is to use a sentinel value as the last element (similar to the 0 terminator in strings) - some out-of-band value that can't happen in normal input (like a negative age, or blank name, or similar).  Then you loop until you see that sentinel.

Comment: @Lundin Arduino C++, I'm updating the tags for this. Apologies

Comment: @Lundin I'm allocating the memory on the function readFromFile(). This is actually reading a JSON, using deserializeJSON, which actually gives me the number of elements with doc.size(). Then, I'm doing struct person list[doc.size()], and populating it on a for loop. Lastly, returning list as the array that contains all the people there. Probably intrincate and ineficcient, but I'm learning...!

Comment: Again, why on earth are you doing that on an Arduino? It's not a PC.

Comment: I'm starting to be curious where is this question coming from: Why? because I want to experiment, becuse the project I'm trying to pull out requires so, because it's an exercise to see the capabilities of my microcontroller... in short, because why not :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using "String" (Whatever that is in your case.), use a fixed array of char for each string.

Like so:

```
struct person
{
     char name[32], /* string name has a length of 31 + 1 for NULL-termination */
     char city[32], /* string city has a length of 31 + 1 for NULL-termination */
     int age
}
```

Comment: Despite my reluctancy to use char instead of String, I ended up using this as the pure only way of getting rid of my problems.... thanks!

Comment: No problem. You should also add the following modifier to your struct: `__attribute__((__packed__))`, it ensures that your struct will be always of the same byte-size, even on different CPU architectures. By the way, when working with pointers over structs, it's always a good idea to use the most basic data-types (if possible) within that struct. Or at least use other packed structs as data-types within that struct, which characteristics **you exactly know**.